# Conditionally hiding left hand navigation menu in Volusion

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, volusion

I'm currently attempting to set up a Volusion e-commerce store at the following address:
http://xlevj.jyetp.servertrust.com

My current site template makes use of a side Navigation menu, which I have designated with "Info Links".

My question is this. I would only like to show the "Info Links" menu on article pages(i.e. not product or category pages). Is it possible to somehow detect the type of page the user is currently viewing, then add a simple display:none; to the leftNav div? I know the Volusion platform has a few qwerks that could potentially make it possible, I just cant find any documentation.

Example of an article page that should show the left hand nav:
http://xlevj.jyetp.servertrust.com/help.asp

Example of a product page and category page that should NOT show it:
http://xlevj.jyetp.servertrust.com/Guitar-s/1820.htm

http://xlevj.jyetp.servertrust.com/Asheville-Ag505-Acoustic-Guitar-Natural-Finish-p/5697.htm

Comment: If you have different templates like "Product Template", "Text Template" - then you could add a unique identifier to the `<body>` tag for example a class, then you could hide the nav based on that.

Comment: Yea, I like the idea of conditionally adding a tag to the body element. That would make it extremely easy! Unfortunately, the volusion platform only uses a single template throughout the site. I've seen the homepage targeted in this manner with a simple id tag, and I was hoping someone knew if one could target product pages in the same manner. As you can see, the site homepage does not have the left hand menu!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this a couple different ways on Volusion. The key is that there are unique elements to both the product and category pages.A simple way to do this is to detect the type of page based on the URL.

Volusion Product Page URLs all contain "-p/" (or alternatively "_p/")
Volusion Category Page URLs all contain "-s/" (or alternatively "_s/")

So, you might do something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){         
     var pathname = window.location.pathname;
     if(pathname.indexOf('-p/') > -1){
        $('body').addClass('product-page');
     }     
});
```

Then just add the appropriate CSS with a display:none for the left nav.